# parsing with dom4j

Tags: parsing, dom4j

I am successfully retrieve the data of **response** using xpath expression **/abcde/response** from the xml ,

```xml
<abcde>
            <response>000</response>
</abcde>
```

But couldnt retrieve the data of **response** from the same xml but with some additional data

```xml
<abcde version="8.1" xmlns="http://www.litle.com/schema"
      response="0" message="Valid Format">
            <response>000</response>
</abcde>
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

```java
package stackoverflow;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.DocumentFactory;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
import org.dom4j.XPath;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;
import org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath;
import org.jaxen.VariableContext;

public class MakejdomWork {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MakejdomWork().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream("<abcde version=\"8.1\" xmlns=\"http://www.litle.com/schema\"      response=\"0\" message=\"Valid Format\">            <response>000</response></abcde>".getBytes());
        //ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream("<abcde><response>000</response></abcde>".getBytes());

        Map nsPrefixes = new HashMap();
        nsPrefixes.put( "x", "http://www.litle.com/schema" );

        DocumentFactory factory = new DocumentFactory();
        factory.setXPathNamespaceURIs( nsPrefixes );

        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        reader.setDocumentFactory( factory );
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = reader.read( bis );
            Object value = doc.valueOf("/abcde/x:response");
            System.out.println(value);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Short answer: you need to use namespace prefixes if your parser is namespace aware (which dom4j is)